# Android Wear: How to make REST POST API call?

Tags: android, rest, post, retrofit2, wear-os

I was trying to use Retrofit to make a REST POST Api call from Android Wear. My Android Wear is connected to smartphone via Bluetooth.

I keep getting `SocketTimeoutException`.

However, the same code works fine and successfully makes POST Api call from a test app in smartphone.

Any mistake I am doing? How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Which REST endpoint are you trying to hit?  Are you certain that the wear device actually has a network connection?  Note that if you are trying to hit something running on localhost, it would need to connect to your local network.

Comment: End point is hosted on the Wifi network. Additionally, I am able to access the api from the same code in a test app in smartphone.

Comment: Your gear device is probably not connected to your local router, or at least not connected in a stable way.  You should text for this now.

Comment: Gear is connected to smartphone, and smartphone is connected to the Wifi network.

Comment: You should update your question with the IP address for the phone and gear device.